# Android - How can I reference string from EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

basically I have a text view that displays the default status of the user

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clickable_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="editStatus"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:text="Online"/>
```

When I tap on this, the keyboard opens and it converts to an EditText. When this happens, there is a new button that appears that will say "Save Status". What I want is for this to do is when I tap the "Save Status" button, it will create a new text view, where the use inputted text will display. This is my code, but I've got red squigglies under `new TextView(this)` and `linearLayout`.

```
    private OnClickListener keyboard = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Hide Keyboard
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus()
                .getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        // Hide EditText
        EditText status = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hidden_edit_view);
        status.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // Get inputtes text
        String text = status.getText().toString();
        // Display text in TextView
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contactlist);
        TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setText(text);
        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);
```

Comment: What does it say in red for the linearlayout? that seems like it should be fine.

Comment: Only thing I see wrong is that maybe you meant `layout` instead of `linearLayout`.

Comment: It said "LinearLayout cannot be resolved to a variable". It went away once I removed the `)` after linearLayout, but then it told me "Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression"

Comment: Ah hah! plain layout worked great. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to reference the outer class instead by doing:

```
TextView valueTV = new TextView(YourActivity.this);
```

Since when you use just `this` inside the inner class, you are referencing the inner class instance, which isn't a `Context`, it's an `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Ok, this worked for that line of code but I'm still having problems with the linearLayout part. Thanks